# Capybara - finding an element with Id & text or using multiple properties

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have 2 links with same id 2 and different text

```
<li class=""> 
<a href="#" id="2">2</a>
</li>

<li class="">
<a href="#" id="2">Next</a>
</li>
```

now i wanted to write something like

```
page.find_by_id("2").has_text?("2")
```

but it is not working not sure how to find the element with id = "2" & text ="2"

I am getting error

```
Capybara::Ambiguous: Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching id "2"
```

Comment: Fix your html -- According to the spec ids have to be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last link with id "2":

```
page.all(:css, "a[id='2']").last()
```

To get the first link with id "2" and text "Next":

```
page.find(:xpath, "//a[@id='2'][text()='Next']")
```

To get the first link with text "Next":

```
page.find_link("Next")
```

Comment: You're second example is probably easier to read written as `page.find(:css, 'a[@id="2"]', text: 'Next')`

Comment: Thanks Florent, 

why are we using .last() for page.find(:xpath, "//a[@id='2'][text()='Next']").last()

will it not bring unique result ?

Comment: @Achyuth Pydmarri, it was a copy/pate mistake.

Comment: Thanks Tom

i am new to this wanted to understand the usage of :css ?

Comment: @AchyuthPydmarri :css just states that the following string is a CSS selector (as opposed to an :xpath, or something else).  By default Capybara.default_selector == :css so  unless you've changed it  `find(:css, '#id')` is the same as `find('#id')`

Comment: @Tom Walpole, you're right it would be easier to read with a CSS selector and the text as a parameter. Feel free to write it as your own answer.